# How can I rewrite URLs (website.com to www.website.com, for example)?

Tags: c#, url, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite URLs on every page, as follows:

- `website.com` to `www.website.com`
- `website.com/page1.aspx` to `www.website.com/page1.aspx`
- etc.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "rewrite"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well if we are talking apache, then in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

for IIS and web.config, go with

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
    <rule name="Canonical Host Name" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.website\.com$" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{MapSSL:{HTTPS}}www.website.com/{R:1}"    redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
</rules>
<rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="MapSSL" defaultValue="OFF">
        <add key="ON" value="https://" />
        <add key="OFF" value="http://" />
    </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: ASP.NET C#, what what i think is the solution is a rule rewrite just like that in web.config but i cannot seem to find it

Comment: ok i tweaked it for iis also

Comment: "500 page error" after i had it to web.config, i will mess around with it some more to see if i can fix it

Comment: it was a conflict with another rule, it's working, thanks alot ^^

Comment: it's always a good thing when a rewrite works ! oh the hrs we spend with regular expressions :>

Answer (score 0):

IIS does have a rewrite module that will allow you to do what you want http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite.

Comment: What would be the code to rewrite after install?